# Bootstrap: adding gaps between divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If my page uses the Bootstrap class `row`, `col-md-x` and such to arrange the content, what would be the proper way to create a distance between each div containing a whole element semantically speaking?

I am adding a div with a padding between the divs to simulate the gap, is this a good tactic or is there a better one?

Comment: Don't you just want to add a margin to `row`? Like `.row { margin-bottom: 40px; }`?

Comment: [`col-md-offset-N`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)?

Comment: @m59 Maybe, but not for every `.row` div... I don't want to mess with the Bootstrap CSS properties and change them. @Jonathan Lonowski isn't that for horizontal positioning?

Comment: @dabadaba then add your own class to the rows you want to change, like `.spaced-row` and add the margin to that.

Comment: @dabadaba You didn't really specify "*vertically*." Just a "*gap between divs*" after mentioning both row and column divs, suggesting you could want either or both vertical and horizontal spacing. But, yes, `offset` classes will only help with horizontal.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Adding a padding between the divs to simulate a gap might be a hack, but why not use something Bootstrap provides. It's called offsets. But again, you can define a class in your **custom.css** (you shouldn't edit the core stylesheet anyway) file and add something like `.gap`. However, `.col-md-offset-*` does the job most of the times for me, allowing me to precisely leave a gap between the divs.

As for vertical spacing, unfortunately, there isn't anything set built-in like that in Bootstrap 3, so you will have to invent your own custom class to do that. I'd usually do something like `.top-buffer { margin-top:20px; }`. This does the trick, and obviously, it doesn't have to be 20px, it can be anything you like.

Comment: That's what I am looking for, something that Bootstrap already gives you to do that. But as far as I know offset only helps to position divs horizontally, not vertically, and I want to create the gap between divs placed below another.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response, that's how I'll do it.

Comment: what if I have 4 divs having class .col-md-4 in a row and I want to add space after first 3?

Answer (score 63):

Starting from Bootstrap v4 you can simply add the following to your `div` class attribute: **mt-2** (margin top 2)

```
<div class="mt-2 col-md-12">
        This will have a two-point top margin!
</div>
```

More examples are given in the docs: [Bootstrap v4 docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/)

Answer (score 23):

I required only one instance of the vertical padding, so I inserted this line in the appropriate place to avoid adding more to the css. `<div style="margin-top:5px"></div>`

Comment: That works. But convention of a good developer is to keep the assets separately. It is best to define a class or reference to your div id in a separate css file. Trust me when I say this, in webdesign, singletons are rare !

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do it is to add `mb-5` to your classes. That is `<div class='row mb-5'>`.

**NOTE**:

- `mb` varies betweeen 1 to 5
- The Div MUST have the row class

Comment: Thanks for answer, I need vertical way.

Comment: @hakanaltindis see these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989515/bootstrap-add-margin-padding-space-between-columns

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to accomplish what you are asking, **without having problems on the mobile version** of your website, (*Remember that the margin attribute will brake your responsive layout on mobile version thus you have to add on your element a supplementary attribute like `@media (min-width:768px){ 'your-class'{margin:0}}` to override the previous margin*)

> is to nest your class in your preferred div and then add on your class
>   the margin option you want

like the following example:
HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
   <div class="events">
     <img src="..."  class="img-responsive" alt="...."/>
     <div class="figcaption">
       <h2>Event Title</h2>
       <p>Event Description.</p>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
   <div class="events">
    <img src="..."  class="img-responsive" alt="...."/>
    <div class="figcaption">
     <h2>Event Title</h2>
     <p>Event Description. </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
   <div class="events">
    <img src="..."  class="img-responsive" alt="...."/>
    <div class="figcaption">
     <h2>Event Title</h2>
     <p>Event Description. </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And on your CSS you just add the margin option on your class which in this example is "events" like:

```
.events{
margin: 20px 10px;
}
```

By this method you will have all the wanted space between your divs making sure you do not brake anything on your website's mobile and tablet versions.