# Bootstrap: add margin/padding space between columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to put some extra margin/padding space between columns on my Bootstrap grid layout. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738712/twitter-bootstrap-grid-system-spacing-between-columns) but I don't like the result. Here is my code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center col-md-6">
            Widget 1
        </div>
        <div class="text-center col-md-6">
            Widget 2
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to add `margin: 10px` and `padding:10px`. Some people suggest to change their classes to `col-md-5` with `pull-left` and `pull-right`, but the gap between them will be too large.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5** (Update 2021)

Bootstrap 5 has still includes spacing utilities for padding. However, because of new RTL support "left" and "right" have been changed to "start" and "end". For example `pl-2` is now `ps-2`.

- `pl-*` => `ps-*` (padding-left)
- `pr-*` => `pe-*` (padding-right)
- `ml-*` => `ms-*` (margin-left)
- `mr-*` => `me-*` (margin-right)

Additionally, Bootstrap 5 introduces new [grid gutter classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#gutters) that can be used to adjust the spacing between columns. The guttter is set on the `row` instead of each `col-*` inside the row. For example, use `g-0` for no spacing between columns.

[Bootstrap 5 column spacing demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/Mvf9kSXNxH)

---

**Bootstrap 4** (Update 2018)

Bootstrap 4 has [spacing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) that make adding (or substracting) the space (gutter) between columns easier. **Extra CSS isn't necessary**.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="text-center col-md-6">
        <div class="mr-2">Widget 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center col-md-6">
        <div class="ml-2">Widget 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can **adjust margins on the column contents** using the *margin* utils such as `ml-0` (margin-left:0), `mr-0` (margin-right:0), `mx-1` (.25rem left & right margins), etc...

***Or,*** you can **adjust padding on the columns** (col-*) using the *padding* utils such as pl-0 (padding-left:0), pr-0 (padding-right:0), px-2 (.50rem left & right padding), etc...

[Bootstrap 4 Column Spacing Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/LN7xDgslxh/bootstrap-4-space-between-columns)

**Notes**

- Changing the left/right margin(s) on `col-*` will break the grid.
- Change the left/right margin(s) on the content of  `col-*` works.
- Change the left/right padding on the `col-*` also works.

Comment: It's not made clear what `mx` means nor what the `mr-2` is on the div in the `col` div and not a property of the col itself like ` <div class="text-center col-md-6 mr-2">`

Comment: @BerndWechner the answer doesn't need to explain x refers to x-axis (horizontal) margins, because the OP didn't specifically ask that. And as far as "*nor what the mr-2 is on the div in the col div and not a property of the col itself*" read the part that says "**Changing the left/right margin(s) on col-* will break the grid**" which is a much broader Bootstrap grid concept that is again not relevant for answering the OP's question.

Answer (score 104):

Simply add a div within `col-md-6` that has the extra padding that you need.  The `col-md-6` is the 'backbone' to keep the column integrity, but you can add additional padding within it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="text-center col-md-6">
        <div class="classWithPad">Widget 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center col-md-6">
        <div class="classWithPad">Widget 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.classWithPad { margin:10px; padding:10px; }
```

Comment: Great! Nowadays if you use bootstrap > 3, Class "classWithPad" can be just "mb-3", "mt-md-4" etc without extra css

Answer (score 22):

I was facing the same issue; and the following worked well for me. Hope this helps someone landing here:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     Set room heater temperature
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="col-md-12">
     Set room heater temperature
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image]

This will automatically render some space between the 2 divs.

Comment: Yea... but it just feels so dirty.... Why not just make your own class as suggested instead of bodging the bootstrap system.

Comment: bootstrap documentation suggests that a column should be a direct child of a row.

Comment: Works fine but in this, there is no way to adjust that gap.

Comment: Honestly prefer this answer since it does not require any custom css. After all, that is why you use frameworks. Thank you

Comment: this isn't a great answer at all. you should NOT nest columns in the grid.

Answer (score 12):

Just add 'justify-content-around' class. that would automatically add gap between 2 divs.

Documentation:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment

Sample:

```
<div class="row justify-content-around">
    <div class="col-4">
      One of two columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      One of two columns
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Simple solution. Thanks for sharing

Comment: This is the answer. Remove the above ones.

Comment: Tested with `Bootstrap v5.x` and works great.

Answer (score 5):

You may use the padding and margin shorthand Bootstrap 4 classes as follows:

For extra small devices i.e. xs

```
{property}{sides}-{size}
```

For other devices/viewports (small, medium, large and extra large)

```
{property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size}
```

Where:

```
property = m for margin and p for padding
```

Following are sides shorthand meanings:

```
l = defines the left-margin or left-padding
r = defines the right-margin or right-padding
t = defines the top-margin or top-padding
b = defines the bottom-margin or right-padding
x = For setting left and right padding and margins by the single call
y = For setting top and bottom margins
blank = margin and padding for all sides
```

The breakpoint = sm, md, lg, and xl.

Combining all the above, the left padding complete code can be (for example):

For left padding in extra small devices

pl-2

or for medium to extra large

pl-md-2

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="text-center col-md-6">
       <div class="col-md-12"> 
          Widget 1
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12"> 
          Widget 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is your answer different from the previous one? By centering content of the column?

Answer (score 1):

I would keep an extra column in the middle for larger displays and reset to default when the columns collapse on smaller displays. Something like this:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center col-md-5 col-sm-6">
            Widget 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <!-- Gap between columns -->
        </div>
        <div class="text-center col-md-5 col-sm-6">
            Widget 2
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Super easy with flexbox. Leave room for some space by changing the columns to `col-md-5`

```
<div class="row widgets">
    <div class="text-center col-md-5">
        Widget 1
    </div>
    <div class="text-center col-md-5">
        Widget 2
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.widgets {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: In Bootstrap 4 you can use the built-in class `.justify-content-between` in place of `.widgets` here.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking to control the space between a dynamic number of columns, try:

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="inner">
            <!-- content here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="inner">
            <!-- content here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- etc. -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col:not(:last-child) .inner {
  margin: 2px; // Or whatever you want your spacing to be
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution for someone like me when cells got background color

HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 cssBox">
            a<br />ba<br />ba<br />b
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 cssBox">
            a<br />b
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cssBox {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 10px;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the otherside if you like to remove double padding between columns just add class "nogap" inside row

```
<div class="row nogap">
    <div class="text-center col-md-6">Widget 1</div>
    <div class="text-center col-md-6">Widget 2</div>
</div>
```

and create additional css class for it

```
.nogap > .col{ padding-left:7.5px; padding-right: 7.5px}
.nogap > .col:first-child{ padding-left: 15px; }
.nogap > .col:last-child{ padding-right: 15px; }
```

Thats it, check here: https://codepen.io/michal-lukasik/pen/xXvoYJ

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and worked it out by nesting a div inside bootstrap col and adding padding to it. Something like:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="custom-box">Your content with padding</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="custom-box">Your content with padding</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="custom-box">Your content with padding</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a solution that works for me, although it doesnt actually create a space between the boxes so may not be exactly what you are looking for.

border border-white

Doesn't actually create a space but gives the effect of space between cols. Only works if you have a bg-color obviously.

[image: Screenshot Border White]

Answer (score 0):

```
**If you use Bootstrap v4.6 or less than v5+ you can like this:**

**custom css** :

    .customCol{
    padding:"5px"
    }

    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6" >
               <div class="customCol">
               ......
               </div> 
            </div>
    </div>
```

If you use React JS, you can create custom Col Component like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Col } from 'reactstrap';

const ErpCol = ( props ) => {
    const { children, ...rest } = props;
    return (
        <Col
            {...rest}
        >
            <div style={{
                padding: '5px'
            }}>
                {children}
            </div>
        </Col>
    );
};

export default ErpCol;
```

Use link this:

```
<Row>
   <ErpCol>
   ....
  </ErpCo>
</Row>
```

If you use Boostrapv5+, you can read the documentation:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
         Set room heater temperature
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2"></div>
     <div class="col-md-5">
         Set room heater temperature
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -14):

For the more curious, I have also found that adding

```
border: 5px solid white
```

or any other variant of your liking, to make it blend in, works superbly.

Comment: You're adding a white border, not margin.

Comment: I guess you have to truly understand what box model really is.