# Can't add a margin to a Bootstrap grid without whole layout changing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, containers

I'm starting to learn Bootstrap but for some reason I'm having this issue when trying to create a grid. I want it to look like [this image](https://i.gyazo.com/614072d5f4d19807c7e2ac9bc2f6d41a.png), but it just breaks when I try to add a margin-left. I can add a margin-top no problem, but whenever I make it a bit larger horizontally, it all breaks, and it goes from [this](https://i.gyazo.com/366c8f21f663e929642afd6dfc4a2af7.png)
to, whenever I add, for example, "ml-2" to any element, [this.](https://i.gyazo.com/846bfbbf00f407d2b12906d8f6906ecd.png)

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tasca 21</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col" id="top"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="mt-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 xs-hidden" id="left"></div>
        <div class="col-10">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="mt-2 col" id="top2"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" id="mid">
            <div class="mt-2 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
            <div class="mt-2 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" id="cubes">
            <div class="mt-2 col-2"></div>
            <div class="mt-2 col-2"></div>
            <div class="mt-2 col-4"></div>
            <div class="mt-2 col-2"></div>
            <div class="mt-2 col-2"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" id="cubes">
            <div class="mt-2 col-2"></div>
            <div class="mt-2 col-2"></div>
            <div class="mt-2 col-4"></div>
            <div class="mt-2 col-2"></div>
            <div class="mt-2 col-2"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 mt-2" id="bottom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 5em;
}
#top {
  background-color: #2ECC40;
  height: 2em;
}
#bottom {
  background-color: #2ECC40;
  height: 1em;
}
#left {
  background-color: #FF4136;
  height: 14.5em;
}
#top2 {
  background-color: #F012BE;
  height: 2em;
}
#mid div {
  background-color: #FF851B;
  height: 5em;
}
#cubes div {
  background-color: #0074D9;
  height: 3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your style rules will probably conflict with bootstrap. I suggest that you wrap your rows in a div with your own styles, like this:

```html
<div id="cubes">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="mt-2 col-2"></div>
    <div class="mt-2 col-2"></div>
    <div class="mt-2 col-4"></div>
    <div class="mt-2 col-2"></div>
    <div class="mt-2 col-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

that will eliminate possible conflicts

Comment: Didn't work, tried to wrap every single row in its own div, but didn't really change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the left/right margins *will* change [how the grid works](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#how-it-works) since the **negative margins on the `row`** specifically relate to the padding (gutter) on the columns.

If you want to change the spacing between columns it's better to **use *padding* on the columns**, or ***margins* on the content of the columns**, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989515/bootstrap-add-margin-padding-space-between-columns).