# How to change margin size based on screen size breakpoints?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a row of reactstrap cards that are dynamically placed in rows, and for "md" screen sizes and up (bootstrap), there will be 3 cards per row, and for lower it'll be 2 cards.

Here's the component:

```
<Card
    outline
    as='a'
    style={{ cursor: 'pointer', margin: '1rem' }}
  >
    <CardImg top width='100%' src={img}' />
    <CardBody>
      <CardTitle tag='h5'>{this.props.title}</CardTitle>
    </CardBody>
  </Card>
```

My problem is, I want only the middle card to have margins on the sides (marginLeft: '1rem', marginRight: '1rem').

Since the number of cards in a row changes based on screensize, I can't just say "if it's a multiple of x, then have this style". Unless I know the screensize, so is there a way to create a prop in my parent component that I can pass into my card component to let it know what to set the margin as?

Thanks

(Any better suggestions are welcome)

More code:

```
render () {
    return (
        ...
        <div className='row' style={{margin:'0rem'}}>
            {
                disp.map((d, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className='col-md-4 col-6 d-flex'>
                            <the card component here>
                        </div
                    )
                    ...
                }
            }
        </div>
    ....
```

Comment: If there is a row of multiple cards in it and If I am not wrong then you want space in between that's why you are adding maring. Is that right?

Comment: yes, I want space between each card, but I don't want extra margins on the side of the entire grid @decpk

Answer (score 0):

If you want space in between the children then you can use `gap` and using `flexbox`. But `gap` property doesn't have great support.

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-container {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 100px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .card-container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .card {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">card1</div>
  <div class="card">card1</div>
  <div class="card">card1</div>
</div>
```

So you can use

```
[parent-selector] > * + *
```

Above selector means select all children that are siblings of any element and which is direct child of `parent-selector(use class for parent or HTML element)`.

If the structure is from top to bottom or in row view then you can use

```
.card-container > * + * {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

and if you want space in between when the elements are arrange in left to right or in columns then use

```
.card-container > * + * {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-container {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 100px;
}

.card-container>*+* {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .card-container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .card {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .card-container>*+* {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">card1</div>
  <div class="card">card1</div>
  <div class="card">card1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: there's still margins on the left and right cards though. is there a way to keep the margins 0 for the very ends?

Comment: @chung Edited. BTW that's the padding on the `.card-container` and `margin` of `body` added by `browser`

Comment: see [codepen example here](https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/MWmvpzN)

Comment: thanks! and sorry, Im not sure how to implement bootstrap in codepen, but could you send a snippet with 6 cards? 3 on each row and see if each row looks the same?

Comment: see [codepen](https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/MWmvpzN?editors=1100) Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

> "How to change margin size based on screen size breakpoints?"

That's exactly what the [Bootstrap responsive spacing classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/) are used for. But, if you're using the grid (Row > Col) it's better to use padding (*not margins*) to [adjust the spacing between columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989515/bootstrap-add-margin-padding-space-between-columns/48912617#48912617).

Assuming you're using the column classes `col-6 col-md-4` to get "*for "md" screen sizes and up, there will be 3 cards per row, and for lower it'll be 2 cards.*"...

You can responsively adjust the padding on the columns, or the margin in the cards. For example, here's 3 margin units on md and up (`mx-md-3`), and 1 margin unit (`mx-1`) on lower:

```
   <Col className="col-6 col-md-4 py-3">
        <Card className="mx-1 mx-md-3">
           ...
        </Card>
   </Col>
```

[React on Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/hzRZURfyrC)

Comment: sorry I should have been more specific, I'm dynamically adding the cards using .map. So I do .map(x, index) => { return (<card ....) } . and I can do that x times. each row will have 3 cards on medium size (where I want to add the side margins ONLY to the middle one) and on small screens I'll have 2 cards in each row, so margin left on the right card, margin right on the left card to keep the distance the same. So I can't just add one className to all the cards

Comment: added some more details to post

Comment: So then you can use the margin classes however you want as I've shown. Do you understand that the columns already have spacing/gutter between them that uses padding?

Comment: Please accept the answer to others know the question is solved